# iOS program structuring - SQLite and View Controllers

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm looking to get some insight on a project of mine before I get too deep into it with possibly a poor setup. The app is a simple database collection with a few table views.

Quick example:
First table view is populated with teacher names. Select the teacher and the next table view is populated with all of the students in that class. Further, select that student and an info view arises with details for that student.

The plan is to use SQLite, so I'm looking to make sure I set views up properly to make it easier on myself later.

My thoughts so far:

TeacherViewController - Grab info from DB to populate the table view. Contains segue within didSelectRowAtIndexPath to jump to StudentView.

StudentViewController - Again grabs info from the DB from that teacher's table to populate with students, with a segue to jump to info page.

StudentInfoView - Contains the forms ready to be populated with info.

There needs to be the ability to add teachers, as well as add students within each teacher/class. Since I haven't dove into SQLite yet, I'd like advice from those experienced.

Thanks, and let me answer any questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing I have found when using SQLite is to ensure that you arrange your views in line with large data captures.

For instance I have a word game and the most intense call to the DB is to generate the starting position of the game. So I do this in a separate thread whilst playing a tutorial, when the viewController first loads. The rest of the calls are quick and easy so can be done at the required time within the game without any impact on performance (i.e. this includes lines like select count(*) from six where word = '%@' - where the DB table has 22000 words)

You will find that sqlite calls are very quick. I think your approach sounds fine as the large calls will be done on the load of the viewControllers where you can easily add loading indicators.

One thing to bare in mind - which can get an app rejected is where you store the sqlite db - because if it is to large then you need to ensure that it isn't backed up via iCloud without asking the user for permission.